# How to create subcollections programmatically with React Native Firestore

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I am looking to create subcollections with React Native Firebase to create a firestore structure like this:

```
groups
   ->group
      ->scheduledQuestionnaires
         ->questionnaire (fields: id, type and timestamp)
```

```
users
   ->user
      ->groups
         (fields: id and name)
```

I have created the collections `groups` and `users`, but how can I create a subcollection `scheduledQuestionnaires` for every group programmatically.

I am able to add documents with fields to collections just fine, but I can't seem to find a way to create (sub)collections. Am I going the wrong way about it or am I missing something?

---

**EDIT**
To add to the answer by monsty. Here is a code snippet of what I wanted to do:

```
 firestore()
    .collection('groups')
    .doc('group1/scheduledQuestionnaires/questionnaire1')
    .set({
       id: '1',
       type: 'type',
       timestamp: 'timestamp',
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create subcollections for every collection, because Firebase will handle it.

If you try to save a document into "/groups/group/scheduledQuestionnaires/hello/world/my_document", Firebase will create all the sub collections needed (in this case : hello and world).